# How to implement chat in an app which uses facebook-ios-sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, chat, quickblox

I am developing an iphone app which uses facebook-ios-sdk. For chating i used quickblox sdk. But it results a mac-o-linker error. Is there any other sdk fot chat ?

Comment: Can you provide more details about the error and how you're implementing the SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have one idea why you have this error: QuickBlox iOS SDK & Facebook SDK  - both of them use SBJSON lib. Solution - try to delete SBJSON from your project(from Facebook SDK src) (also remove all #import constructions, that use SBJSON) and try build your project.

Hope this topic helps to resolve this issue http://community.quickblox.com/quickblox/topics/json_functions_not_available

Also, please look at this project src  https://github.com/QuickBlox/ChattAR-ios - project featuring Facebook API, Location, Chat and Augmented Reality view. It uses QuickBlox SDK & FB sdk. And both of them work well.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now all the errors are removed but chat is not working fine. I will try it once again.